# UUID fstab configuration in virtual machine ( VMware )

Tags: linux, hard-drive, vmware-player, fstab, uuid

we have physical machines as HP or IBM blade machine and we set UUID in fstab on these physical machines

but in case we use VM ( virtual machine , )

is it necessary to defines UUID in fstab on virtual machine ?

or we can set the ordinary fstab configuration as disk devise against mount point folder ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to define UUIDs, at all. You can still use /dev/sda or /dev/sda1 or whatever your devices are called.

The advantage of the UUID is that they don't change after reboots, what might happen with the /dev/sd[a-z] name assignments, so UUIDs are generally preferred.

This also applies to GRUB.

You can find an [introduction to UUIDs here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID).